# Memcache and ASP.NET runtime cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached

I have a web app which is using Dependency injection allowing me to easily swap between cache implementations. I am currently using the asp.net runtime cache but the web app now needs to be distributed across three web server. I have built an implementation of Memcache and have tested it out and it works, but I am not happy with the speed. I believe the reason is because of the serialization and the deserialization. I am at a loss as to how to speed this up.

I could -

- Leave it and hope the user experience doesn't turn out to be terrible
- Make some data use the runtime cache and some data use memcache
- Figure out how to improve the performance of memcache

p.s. I am trying to avoid using proto-buf for serialization/deserialization because I don't want to decorate my entire domain with attributes (or maybe I should?)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how do you know it is slower? Or how would you know it is serialisation?

I have recently spent a lot of time on performance optimisation and before proposing a solution I must say you need to explore the problem first **based on hard facts**:

1. Establish a baseline benchmark without memcached
2. Run the same benchmark test with memcached and compare
3. If it is definitely slower, use a profiling tool to establish where exactly is your bottleneck
4. After you have established your bottleneck, try to isolate that area of code and create an isolated test case outside your project. Then try to find out why it takes longer and try different approaches. (I and others could help you at that time)

From my experience, serialisation should not be that slow.

In order to benchmark, you can use ab.exe or jmeter both of them free.